# Red-lang Event: symetric of over (not-over)?

Tags: rebol, red

https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html

over

mouse
Mouse cursor passing over a face. This event is produced once when the mouse enters the face and once when it exits. If flags facet contains all‑over flag, then all intermediary events are produced too.

There is no symetric event ? How do I know mouse is not over anymore ?

In rebol there was http://www.rebol.com/how-to/feel.html
but this syntax doesn't exist anymore in Red or I am mistaken ?

```
    view layout [
        box "A Box" forest feel [
            over: func [face act pos] [print [act pos]]
        ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

No symetric event is needed as you can use the `event/away?` flag to check if the `over` event is exiting the face area. See https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html#_event_datatype

`feel` in Rebol/VID is just a keyword for listing event handlers, it's not needed in Red/VID, as event handlers are first-class citizens. So in Red/VID, you would write it:

```
view [box "A Box" forest on-over [print [event/offset event/away?]]]
```